# Exception in Facebook Like button for android apps

Tags: android, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I have setup correctly the facebook SDK for facebook like button. It works fine on one phone (Android 4.3) but gives an exception on the other (Android 4.4.4)

The exception is as:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.compzets.popopics/com.compzets.popopics.ui.MainPagerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LikeView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LikeView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
    at com.compzets.popopics.ui.MainPagerActivity.onCreate(MainPagerActivity.java:58)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.widget.LikeView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.compzets.popopics-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.compzets.popopics-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    ... 22 more
```

It gives a `ClassNotFoundException`, I have no clue as to why it happens? And if there is an issue then why it isn't reflected on both phones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue some days back and the following solved it:

1. Removed `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'` from the dependencies in gradle
2. Synced it
3. Added the same dependency again
4. Again Synced it

Hope this works for you as well!

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! But still I don't get the reason as to why it happened. Earlier it worked on my phone in which i was developing/testing but when i ran the `.apk` on other phones it gave the above exception. Now its running on all phones. Thanks again!